# How to access UIComponent in JSF page onPageLoad or after it immidetaliy

Tags: java, jsf, user-interface, oracle-adf, pageload

Basically, I need to set the `UIComponent` Values and properties on page load and before rendering the page to the user. I tried to use `PagePhaseListener` where I am using `onPageLoad` method to access `UIComponents` but I always get `NullPointerException`. After Searching I realizes the reason behind this Exception, that is because there is no `UIComponents` rendered in the page yet.

Also, I tried to use `ADF` `TaskFlow` where I tried to use `methodCall` before going to the page. But, again I got the same result which is `NullPointerException`.

**Summary**: How to execute any logic form `Bean` Class and reflect the result of this logic in `UIComponent` on Page Load.

I am using `Jdeveloper 11g with ADF Techonlogy and JSF pages`

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that, ie what you need to customize? I've very rarely seen uses for this since so much can be done in the view nowadays.

Comment: @mabi that's true, I could do many things in the view objects. Actually, I could do other solution but this in some situation time consuming. So, I thought I could have extra tool and management on the page. Example of use-case is to auto select specific option form List of Values where the user still can change the selection.